# textract cannot find a pdf file python

Tags: python, file, pdf

I have the following simple code:

```
import textract

text = textract.process("text.pdf")
```

However, I got the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

But I am sure that I have a file called `text.pdf` in the current directory. Nevertheless, if I create a document called `a.txt` and change the second line of the code to:

```
text = textract.process("a.txt", extension='txt')
```

Then the problem disappears. I also tried:

```
text = textract.process("text.pdf", extension='pdf')
```

But I got the same error as before.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem and solved it by installing pdftotext in addition.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pdftotext
```

If pdftotext is missing textract will use a fall back that seems to have issues.